# Elasticsearch condition on sorting in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

For single field sorting I am using this code

```
searchSourceBuilder.sort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("count").order(SortOrder.DESC));
```

but now I need to add condition like this

```
searchSourceBuilder.sort(SortBuilders.fieldSort(count <= 0 ? "visitor":"visitor" * "count").order(SortOrder.DESC));
```

I am not getting any clue to do this. Is it possible at elasticsearch or I need to do it another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to use is `SortBuilders.scriptSort()` ([script-based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#_script_based_sorting)), like this:

```
Script script = new Script( "doc.count.value <= 0 ? doc.visitor.value : doc.visitor.value * doc.count.value");
SortBuilders.scriptSort(script, ScriptSortType.NUMBER).order(SortOrder.DESC);
```